# How To get data from firestore of current user in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter

I want to get data of authenticated user  from firestore and put them in variables in flutter, I do not need to display them on the screen I  just want to store them in variables  : I created file data.dart It has only variables . this is the file contains the variables(data.dart) (I dont have statefull widget or stateless widget) :
[image: Data.dart]

and this is the file where I called The variables(firbaseapi.dart):

[image: firebaseapi.dart]

```
String myId = "AfhUxYFIaHTvSOyOPlh14essssq9pJpW2"; // I want to get user id here
String myUsername = 'Sabri'; // I want to get username here
String myUrlAvatar = 'http//kdkskdskd'; // I want to get  avatar URL here
```

I tried this but I got an error :
A value of type 'Future' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'DocumentSnapshot'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'DocumentSnapshot'

```
User user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
DocumentSnapshot snap = 
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users').doc(user.uid).get();//error appear here     
     String myId = snap['uid'];
     String myUsername = snap['name'];
     String myUrlAvatar = snap['avatarurl'];
```

Comment: maybe you could give more details on your firestore collection and it's document

Answer (score 1):

working example!

imports

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
```

Global

```
final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
String myId = '';
String myUsername = '';
String myUrlAvatar = '';
```

Method to get data from firestore.

```
  void _getdata() async {
 User user = _firebaseAuth.currentUser;
  FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('users')
    .doc(user.uid)
    .snapshots()
    .listen((userData) {
 
    setState(() {
      myId = userData.data()['uid'];
        myUsername = userData.data()['name'];
       myUrlAvatar = userData.data()['avatarurl'];
      
    });
  }
```

Get data when screen starts in a stateful widget you can also call method on button press.

```
  @override
  void initState() {
super.initState();
_getdata();
 }
```

Comment: I created file data.dart It has only variables . this  file contains the variables(data.dart) (I dont have statefull widget or stateless widget) to make setstate ?

Answer (score 0):

```
DocumentSnapshot snap = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('your collection').get();
String myId = snap['myId'];
String myUsername = snap['myUsername'];
String myUrlAvatar = snap['myUrlAvatar'];
```

Update:

```
User user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
DocumentSnapshot snap = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users').doc(user.uid).get();
String myId = snap['uid'];
String myUsername = snap['name'];
String myUrlAvatar = snap['avatarurl'];
```

Comment: I got this error :  ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: type 'Future<DocumentSnapshot>' is not a subtype of type 'DocumentSnapshot' in type cast ...

Comment: FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

DocumentSnapshot snap   = FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('Users')
    .doc(auth.currentUser.uid)
    .get()  as DocumentSnapshot;
String myId = snap['uid'];
String myUsername = snap['name'];
String myUrlAvatar = snap['avatarurl'];

Comment: firebase has changed a lot as right now this is how it worked for me `Object obj = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(uid).get();`